# nagios -- re-check service after "down" machine comes "up"

Tags: nagios

Let's say I have a `nagios` client.  It has a scheduled downtime from 8am Monday through 8am Tuesday, and the machine is turned off for the entire duration.

There is a service check it performs once per day

```
check_interval      1440
```

Let's say the check happens to be scheduled for 8pm.  So at 8pm Monday, the check happens, and it fails, and `nagios` does nothing because scheduled downtime.

Tuesday at 8am.  The machine comes back on.  But that one service will remain in the `CRITICAL` state until 8pm when the next scheduled check happens.

Is there some way that I can tell `nagios` "Maintain the `check interval 1440`; but, if you see the machine go down and come back up, then force a re-check regardless of the interval" ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from another forum.

I attached an event handler (TIL) to my host object:

```
define host{
    use     linux-server    ; Inherit default values from a template
    host_name   volvo      ; The name we're giving to this host
    alias       volvo  ; A longer name associated with the host
    event_handler       host_state_change
    }
```

Associated my new event_handler name to a shell script

```
define command{
        command_name    host_state_change
        command_line    $USER1$/eventhandlers/hostup.sh $HOSTNAME$ $HOSTSTATE$
    }
```

And created a script that checks what the new state is (that is, it changed from DOWN to UP, so I'm looking for UP) and forces a service check through the command file

```
    printf "[%lu] SCHEDULE_FORCED_SVC_CHECK;$hostname;serial_number;$NOW\n" $NOW > $COMMANDFILE
```